# Dynamic Sql VS Temporary Tables

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a stored procedure, in which temporary tables "on delete preserve rows" are created dynamically and data was inserted, when i try to execute any other dynamic sql statement, data in the temporary tables are deleted. But I need a data for further process.

Can any one tell me why data is losing, and what is the solution for this.

Thank you.

Comment: It's "on commit preserve rows", not "on delete".

Comment: Why do you *create* those tables dynamically (presumably each time)? A (global) temporary table in Oracle is usually created only *once* and then used by different sessions.

Comment: @David Aldridge-   I have changed to on commit preserve rows and same thing is happening

Answer (score 0):

Three possible reasons for this:

1. There is an explicit commit.
2. There is an implicit commit (a DDL statement, typically).
3. You are are closing the session and starting a new one.

If you cannot avoid these then you'll have to create a permanent table.